# Unable To Open Doc File After Editing In C#

Tags: c#

I have written following Code to edit bookmarks of Word document., as document is generated doc is visible but if i close the same and tried to open the same doc again the word doc gives error as :

1.Check file permissions for file/ drive.
2.make sure there is sufficient memory and disk space.

```
private void GenerateApplication()
{
object readOnly = true;
object repair = false;
object bookMarkName = "applicantName";
object bookMarkCompany = "firmName";
object bookMarkPost = "postName";

fielName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\AllUsers\Desktop\OperateWordFromC#.dotx";


objDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fielName, ref missingValuesValues, ref readOnly,       ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref repair, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues);

objDoc.Activate();

objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookMarkName).Range.Text = txtApplicantName.Text;       

objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookMarkCompany).Range.Text = txtAppliedCompany.Text;
objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookMarkPost).Range.Text = txtAppliedPost.Text;

string outputFile = @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\ApplicationOf-" + txtApplicantName.Text + ".docx";

bookMarkName = null;
bookMarkCompany = null;
bookMarkPost = null;

Object objSaveAsFile = outputFile;
Object objFileFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;

wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref objSaveAsFile, ref repair, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues,  ref missingValuesValues, ref  missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues, ref missingValuesValues); 
wordApp.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Do you close the file after you save him ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you're opening (which is being referenced by `objDoc`), has its own `.SaveAs` method with the following parameters, details are in the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
objDoc.SaveAs(ref objSaveAsFile, ref objFileFormat, ref objLockComments, 
    ref objPassword, ref objAddToRecentFiles, ref objWritePassword, 
    ref objReadOnlyRecommended, ref objEmbedTrueTypeFonts, 
    ref objSaveNativePictureFormat, ref objSaveFormsData,
    ref objSaveAsAOCELetter, ref objEncoding, ref objInsertLineBreaks,
    ref objAllowSubstitutions, ref objLineEnding, ref objAddBiDiMarks);
```

Hence, save the document this way (instead of referring to `wordApp.ActiveDocument`). You need to declare and initialize the variables above appropriately before you call `SaveAs`.

You should also close the document if you don't need to access it anymore (using `objDoc.Close()`), but at latest before your application closes.

When you later re-open the newly saved document and change it, you can use `.Save()` instead (it does not require any parameters).